# How do I configure the name of my WSGI application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Python web application is called `app`

```
# example.py
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
```

and when I attempt to launch it on AWS-EB using

```
# run.py (set correctly with WSGIPath)
from example import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I get

```
mod_wsgi (pid=22473): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/run.py' 
    does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
```

How to I tell AWS that my application instance is called `app`?

Comment: Yes, good reference (but some of that wasn't working for me; see my related questions).

Comment: If the basic answer doesn't work for you, you should explain what you have tried and why it doesn't work in your question. This way future readers who had the same problem will understand the answer fully.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

mod_wsgi expects variable called `application`. Try to do something like this

```
from example import app as application
```

Note: don't do `application.run()`. It is not needed.

Comment: Wow, so all that's needed by AWS is an instance called `application`; the entire content of `run.py` could be that single import, correct?

Comment: In fact, is it correct to say that for AWS (unlike, say, Heroku) there needs to be no *run* script at all, just a file in which the an instance called `application` is defined.

Comment: Usually for development purposes, module with application contains app.run() in if __name__ == '__main__' section at the bottom of file. Good practice is to create .wsgi file that imports application.

Comment: Yes, understood (fixed above); but is it correct that on AWS running is handled for me ('run.py' is just imported) so that I just need to *define* `application` (in the file that AWS recognizes as `WSGIPath`)? (I can implement that with a single file with `__name__=='__main__'`; but I'm just wondering in the case where I have a distinct file for AWS; all that wold need is the definition, right?)

Comment: [here's a good blog entry explaining how to deal with `application`](http://blog.uptill3.com/2012/08/25/python-on-elastic-beanstalk.html).

Answer (score 8):

While the WSGIPath can be configured. Beanstalk still expects the app variable to be named as 'application'.

A simple workaround for small single file python apps can be

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
application = app # For beanstalk
```

You can keep the rest of the code as is. You just need to add that single line `application = app`